# Stop to refresh data after modifying AppSetting value

Tags: c#, asp.net

After Modifying AppSetting in asp.net,  a pop up is open to reload file update from outsource. how to stop to open pop up and also not to reload all pages control data after pop up close.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after your save call.

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection( "appSettings" );
```

May be u need this